# Electron Problem runing manage.py runserver

Tags: python, django, electron, manage.py

I'm developing a web app, but just yesterday when i try to run manage.py wiht runserver appeared to me this error "(electron) Sending uncompressed crash reports is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Electron. Set { compress: true } to opt-in to the new behavior. Crash reports will be uploaded gzipped, which most crash reporting servers support."

I don't know why appear, I don't changue nothing, I only tunr off my computer.

Can anyone help me whit this?

[Problem Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUO7t.png)

Comment: I would recommend u to use PyCharm and its console

Comment: Hello, I solve the problem uninstalling VS code, I don't know why. but it works, also i wll use PyCharm insted of VS code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem uninstalling VS code, if someone are using VS code and they get this error only that you need to do is uninstalling the program

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken this can be caused by having any program installed which uses electron under the hood. I ran into this issue and I don't have vscode installed. I do however have Atom and Pulsar installed which both use electron.